# Keep only numbers between specific letters

Tags: php, regex

I want to keep a value in several separated long text strings with one part in common. One of the text strings:

```
N-05-0040(119) f 2005 svart hp Ml:153 - 160 - 20 - 75 Tot 31- 3- 3- 6- 13 (4)29,7M - (4)28,2aK Kr 204.500, 2pr 2010, Trener: Ole Olesen
```

The common part is "Kr 204.500," and I only need the numbers, so I can use them for calculations later.

Comment: Does "Kr 204.500," appear in every line and you want to capture another number somewhere else, or does "Kr " always have some number you want followed by a ","?

Comment: You only want to keep the 204.500 number? The number you want to catch is always start by Kr? And, you want the result separated or like 204.500?

Comment: What is consistent about this string? Maybe pull the 22 index on an explode with space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the digits/points after `Kr`, you could use the following expression:

```
Kr\h*    # Kr as string, followed by spaces or tabs
([.\d]+) # capture numbers like 123, 12.5 into the first group
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/zX0nP8/1).

---

In `PHP`:

```
<?php
$string = 'N-05-0040(119) f 2005 svart hp Ml:153 - 160 - 20 - 75 Tot 31- 3- 3- 6- 13 (4)29,7M - (4)28,2aK Kr 204.500, 2pr 2010, Trener: Ole Olesen';

$regex = '~
            Kr\h*    # Kr as string, followed by spaces or tabs
            ([.\d]+) # capture numbers like 123, 12.5 into the first group
          ~x';

preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/1CqIMu).

Comment: This is not a good idea to not initialize the `$matches` variable.

Comment: Got the output as an array, is it possible to get it as a numeric value without the dot?

Comment: @lobirkeland my last solution give you the number on the `$number` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like that:

```
$results = array();

preg_match(
    "/Kr (\d*.?\d*)/",
    "N-05-0040(119) f 2005 svart hp Ml:153 - 160 - 20 - 75 Tot 31- 3- 3- 6- 13 (4)29,7M - (4)28,2aK Kr 204.500, 2pr 2010, Trener: Ole Olesen",
    $results
);

// output: array(
//     0 => Kr 204.500
//     1 => 204.500
// )
```

Then, if you want separate the numbers into array, you need to do that:

```
if (isset($results[1])) {
    $numbers = preg_split("/\./", $results[1]);

    // output = array(
    //     0 => 204
    //     1 => 500
    // )
}
```

---

Edit after your feedback

```
$results = array();

preg_match(
    "/Kr (\d*.?\d*)/",
    "N-05-0040(119) f 2005 svart hp Ml:153 - 160 - 20 - 75 Tot 31- 3- 3- 6- 13 (4)29,7M - (4)28,2aK Kr 204.500, 2pr 2010, Trener: Ole Olesen",
    $results
);

$number = isset($results[1]) ? preg_replace("/\./", "", $results[1]) : null;

// output: 204500
```

Comment: Excuse my low level of knowledge, but i get the the following output: Array 
And nothing else, how can i get the output as an numeric value?

Comment: @lobirkeland You need one or two values? I need the response to help you more.

Comment: I need the two values as one (204500)

Comment: @lobirkeland Added another solution after your feedback. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Making everything optional (`*` and `?`) is almost always a bad idea (backtracking, false positive results, etc.)

Comment: @Jan `Making everything optional (* and ?) is almost always a bad idea.` And why this is a bad idea? Could you be more constructive?

Comment: See yourself: https://regex101.com/r/zX0nP8/2 Additionally, it has a lot of backtracking. One major thing with regular expressions is to *come to an end fast* (successful or not, that is).

Comment: @Jan Yes, I totally agree. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @keupsonite: No worries, +1 :)

Answer (score -1):

Think i maybe have solved it myself..

```
$var = strstr($var, 'Kr. ');
$var = substr($var, 0, strpos($var, ", "));
$var = str_replace("Kr. ","",$var);
$var = str_replace(".","",$var);
```

Thanks for the help! Any suggestions for improvements?

Comment: Congrats! But this is really not the good way to doing that... @Jan and myself have proposed you the best solution.